# How can I configure 403 web page for prohibited territories in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Google Cloud has a [list of prohibited territories](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-prohibited-territories).
So the people in there can't access my website. It's just **loading forever**.
Spotify uses GCP too and they have some kind of fallback page that looks like this: [image]

That page would make it clear that the problem is not in my website but in their location.
How can I configure that 403 page? I'm using GKE if that helps.

Comment: My assumption is that Spotify use a network layer in front of their hosting on Google Cloud. On this layer, they are able to customize things. On Google Cloud, you can't perform this customization. All the Google resources (Google and google cloud) are protected by Google Front End (GFE). And even before landing to your GKE Cluster, the request is discarded by GFE. Thus you can do nothing on GCP.

Comment: Modern multi layer frontend designs can facilitate such provisions, which you can lay at the top of your GKE setup.
Check [here](https://itnext.io/what-are-front-end-service-layers-4dba95db21bb) for details.