# How can I ensure access to a Google Cloud Run service from restricted jurisdictions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm building a simple analytic service that needs to work for multiple countries. It's likely that someone from a restricted jurisdiction (e.g. Iran) hits the endpoint. I am not offering any service that would fall under sanctions-related restrictions, but it seems like Cloud Run endpoints do not allow traffic from places like Iran. I tried various configurations (adding a domain mapping, an external HTTPS LB, calling from Firebase, etc) and it doesn't work.

Is there a way to let read-only traffic through from these territories? Or is there another Google product that would allow this? It seems like the [Google Maps prohibited territory list](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-prohibited-territories) applies to some services, but not others (e.g. Firebase doesn't have this issue).

Comment: As per the comment from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68973122/18265570), looks like gcp services are not supported in prohibited territories.

Answer (score 2):

You should serve traffic through Load Balancer with Cloud Armour policy. Cloud Armour provide a feature for filtering traffic based on location.

Comment: So would Cloud Armour allow me to actually receive traffic from sanctioned countries then? e.g. unlike a HTTP(s) global load balancer without Cloud Armour?